# Error when installing ng2-opd-popup

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

After I install `ng2-opd-popup` I'm getting an error

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/ng2-opd-popup/node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts(24,5): 
>   error TS2416: Property 'lift' in type 'Subject' is not assignable
>   to the same property in base type 'Observable'.

**Package.Json**

```
{
  "name": "my-proj",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ng2-opd-popup": "^1.1.21",
    "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
    "ngx-modal-dialog": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

Can you help me on that?

Comment: Looks like a problem with mismatched `rxjs` versions. Could you post your other dependencies in your `package.json`?

Comment: @Capricorn  please check my package.json

Comment: That library seems to only support angular `^4.0.0` and an old version of rxjs, you're using angular `^6.0.0` and a later release. They are incompatible. Either look for an alternative library, stick with the older versions or follow this GitHub Issue, seems to also be related to outdated rxjs dependency (https://github.com/opdahlmann/ng2-opd-popup-sample/issues/23).